# Diagonalize a quadratic form using Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, diagonalization, gram-schmidt

I'd like to know how to use the Gram-Schmidt method to diagonalize a quadratic form.

I tried to look on the internet for this method but I got no results. My teacher told me I could use Gram-Schmidt method to diagonalize a quadratic form, instead of using the eigenvalues method which is much slower.
Is there anybody here who knows this method? Please, can you explain me how does it work? I really need it.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Either your teacher is confused or you've misunderstood what your teacher told you.

Comment: There are no the Gram-Schmidt method of diagonalization of a quadratic form.  The QR method of finding eigenvalues is closely related to the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: I've added a photo of what he means with "Gram Schmidt diagonalization of a quadratic form".

Answer (score 4):

Your teacher is clearly wrong. If it would be possible to diagonalize a positive definite quadratic form over $\mathbb{Q}$ with the Gram-Schmidt process only, all the eigenvalues of the associated matrix would be algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $2^m$, given the operations involved in the GS process. If, for instance, the characteristic polynomial of our matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ is an irreducible polynomial with degree $3$, we are doomed.

What actually holds is that we may use the Gram-Schmidt process to find [a QR decomposition](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/Teaching/Math151B/handouts/GramSchmidt.pdf), but that's a different story, a QR decomposition is not a diagonalization ($Q^{-1} D Q$).

However, we may use the [$QR$ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) to find an approximate diagonalization. The idea is the following one: we may use GS to write $M$ as $QR$. Then we may consider $M_1=RQ$ and apply GS to $M_1$ to get $M_1=Q_1 R_1$. If we set $M_2=R_1 Q_1$ and continue this way, $R_n$ converges to $D$ and $Q_n$ converges to the matrix $Q$ giving the diagonalization $M=Q^{-1}D Q$.

Comment: I've added a photo of what he means with "Gram Schmidt diagonalization of a quadratic form".

Comment: He means QDQ^t.

Comment: For real orthogonal matrices the inverse and the transpose are the same thing.

Comment: Q is not orthogonal. Given an inner product $<x,y> = x^t A y$, Gram-Schmidt finds a basis in which the inner product looks like the standard inner product, i.e. $<Qx,Qy> = x^t y$. From this we see $Q^t A Q = I$. For indefinite inner products it's not the identity but a matrix with only $1,0,-1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: @Jules: a change of basis is something of the form $M\to J^{-1} N J$. Gram-Schmidt cannot be used for diagonalization, I have already explained *why*. Consider a real, symmetric, positive definite $3\times 3$ random matrix and apply GS to its column space (or anything else): you do not get the eigenvectors of such a matrix, simply because you cannot through $+,-,\cdot, /,\sqrt{}$ only.

Comment: That is for a linear transformation $L : V \rightarrow V$. A quadratic form is $Q : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Therefore a basis transformation looks like $Q(Jx,Jx)$. If $Q$ is given by $Q(x,y) = x^t A y$ you get $J^t A J$.

Comment: Whether or not you call this diagonalisation is a different matter. You're certainly right that this doesn't give you the eigenvalues of the matrix. It does give you a basis transformation such that the quadratic form is diagonal, so that's why we could call it diagonalisation.

Comment: A change of basis preserves the characteristic polynomial and in a diagonal matrix the eigenvalues are the diagonal elements. So you are not performing a change of basis. The final eigenvalues / diagonal elements should be the same as the original eigenvalues.

Comment: A linear transformation on a vector space transforms like that under a basis transformation, but a quadratic form does not. In general a tensor on $V$ is the tensor product of some number of copies of $V$ and some number of copies of $V^*$. A linear transformation is a tensor $V^* \otimes V$. A quadratic form is $V^* \otimes V^*$. You can express tensors with respect to a basis of $V$. The covariant indices transform differently than the contravariant indices. On an abstract vector space it does not even make sense to talk about the eigenvalues of a quadratic form.

Comment: @Jules: all right, but I guess the original meaning of *diagonalization* in the question was finding a set of eigenvectors for the matrix associated to the given quadratic form. That cannot be done through GS only, but of course there is some room for different interpretations here.

Comment: The question sounds like he wants to avoid eigenvalues to me, but what diagonalisation means is indeed a matter of definition.